# How can i implement bot framework in my visual studio code?

Tags: botframework

how can i implement bot framework in my visual studio code ,And what packages are need to be installed for the usage of bot framework in visual studio code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, but I'll try to cover all of the bases bases and include answers for Node/JS/TS as well as C#.

#### Create a Bot

You have 4 options:

1. **Create the bot in Azure:**

   1. In the Azure Portal, Create a resource > Web App Bot > Go through steps and create.
      [image]
   2. Open the "Web App Bot" resource you just created > Build > Download Bot Source Code.
      [image]
2. **[JS/TS/Node ONLY] Create the bot via Yeoman:** (See JavaScript Quickstart below)

   1. `npm install -g yo generator-botbuilder`
   2. `yo botbuilder`.
   3. Follow the steps and generate your bot.

      - [Here's an explanation of the bot template options you can choose from](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/generators/generator-botbuilder#templates)
      - This will automatically install all of the necessary packages.
        [image]
3. **[C# ONLY]**: Use a VSIX template in Visual Studio:**

   1. Download the [BotBuilder V4 VSIX template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BotBuilder.botbuilderv4)
   2. Create a new Project in Visual Studio (you can get more details about each bot template in the link above)
      [image]
4. **Clone a Sample:**

   1. Clone one of [these samples](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples#samples-list)

      - I recommend Basic Bot: [JS/Node](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.basic-bot) / [C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.basic-bot), for something somewhat complex and Simple Prompt: [JS/Node](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/04.simple-prompt) / [C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/04.simple-prompt), for something easier
   2. Follow each sample's `REAMDE.md` for further instruction.
5. **Create it from scratch** as @TobiasC mentioned. I highly recommend against going this route unless you know what you're doing. It is much easier to start with a sample. Using Yeoman to generate an Empty Bot is a good route to go if you want something pretty bare bones.

#### Packages

The required packages really varies depending on what you're going to do with your bot.

**JS/TS/Node**: Here's a snippet of Basic Bot's `package.json`, showing all the packages it uses:

```
"dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "^4.2.0",
    "botbuilder-ai": "^4.2.0",
    "botbuilder-dialogs": "^4.2.0",
    "botframework-config": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "restify": "^7.2.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^8.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^4.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.6"
}
```

**C#** Here's a list of NuGet packages for Basic Bot from the `.csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.9" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.ContentModerator" Version="0.12.1-preview" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language" Version="1.0.1-preview" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder" Version="4.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis" Version="4.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure" Version="4.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs" Version="4.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core" Version="4.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Configuration" Version="4.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Connector" Version="4.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Schema" Version="4.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Graph" Version="1.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.0-beta008">
```

#### Run the Bot

Run `npm start` from within the bot's directory (Node/JS/TS) or press F5 in Visual Studio (C#). By default, the bot will listen for messages at `http://localhost:3978`

#### Testing and Debugging

Use the [BotFramework Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/wiki/Getting-Started) for local testing. See "Botframework Emulator - Getting Started" below.

#### General

Really, I recommend following the docs and samples as much as possible and using the SDK Reference, when necessary. Links below.

#### References

[JavaScript Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

[C# Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-sdk-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

[Debug a Bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

[Botframework Emulator - Getting Started](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/wiki/Getting-Started)

[The Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

[TS SDK Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/?view=botbuilder-ts-latest)

[C# SDK Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable)

Comment: Hi, 
I am looking to build bot in .Net Framework, so please suggest for the same!

Comment: Are you sure the process you describe is working in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways: Create a Bot within Azure using one of the templates and download the files afterwards or create it from the scratch. The selection of the necessary packages depends on your UseCase. However, basic packages should be:

- restify
- botbuilder
- botbuilder-ai
- botbuilder-dialogs

To run and test the bot locally you will also need the Bot Framework Emulator.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code and want to use .Net Core you can import the following templates. These are found within the README.md of the Generator/template directory on github.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/generators/dotnet-templates

```
# Installs all three templates (echo, core, empty)
dotnet new -i Microsoft.Bot.Framework.CSharp.EchoBot
dotnet new -i Microsoft.Bot.Framework.CSharp.CoreBot
dotnet new -i Microsoft.Bot.Framework.CSharp.EmptyBot
```

then create from the project from the template as you would any other template.

```
# example using the echobot template
dotnet new echobot
```